# Problem with implementing squared terms in the objective function

Tags: optimization, cplex, gurobi

I'm trying to implement either one of these objective functions, but I'm having a hard time with the squared terms. I'm attaching both so you can take a look at the structure and see if you can give me any tips. Is there any way to implement either one of them?

**1- Matrix notation:**

[image]

$x$: decision variable

$1$: column of ones

$k$: squared matrix

**2- Summation notation:**

[image]

$x$: decision variable
$m$: degree of the node i
$rho$: parameter that takes into account the influence of the neighbors that surround node i
$a$: terms of the adjacency matrix. Shows if nodes i and j are connected

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello and welcome to OR.SE. What are the $a_{il}$s and $m_i$s?

Comment: Actually it would be good if you could explain all the notations...

Comment: In what way are you having a hard time? Is the question how to code squared terms with either CPLEX or Gurobi (in which case you should specify what API you are using)?

Comment: @OguzToragay thank you for reaching out! I will edit the post with all the notations.

Comment: @prubin thanks for reaching out! yes, my problem is I don't know how to implement the second term of the objective function in the matrix notation since the term is squared. On the other hand, I tried implementing the second equation of the post, but I run into a memory error. I'm using Gurobi with Python.

Comment: You can enter this straightforwardly in matrix notation in CVXPY, and specify Gurobi as solver. That can reduce error propensity vs. not using matrix formulation. As to whether it will run out of memory in formulation or solution?

Comment: You could always add an auxiliary variable $z=1^T Kx=\sum_i \sum_j K_{ij}x_j$ and then substitute $z^2$ for the squared term in the first formulation.

Answer (score 4):

It's relatively easy to write $(1^{T}Kx)^{2}$ in standard quadratic form.

Since $1^{T}Kx$ is a scalar,

$(1^{T}Kx)^{2}=(1^{T}Kx)(1^{T}Kx)^{T}=1^{T}Kxx^{T}K^{T}1$.

Using the cyclic property of the trace of a product of matrices,

$1^{T}Kxx^{T}K^{T}1=\mbox{tr}(1^{T}Kxx^{T}K^{T}1)=\mbox{tr}(x^{T}K^{T}11^{T}Kx)=x^{T}(K^{T}11^{T}K)x$.

Unfortunately, $K^{T}11^{T}K$ will be dense, so if $x$ is large you'll probably run out of storage.